# Bypass automatic procedures as SQL Server startup

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a number of "autoexec" stored procedures, i.e., marked with:

```
exec sp_procoption 'myproc', 'startup', 'ON';
```

Is there a way to start SQL Server so that the autoexec procedures are *not* executed at startup this time? I need to do this sometimes for certain maintenance operations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the fine manual.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191129(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Although stored procedures are set for automatic execution
>   individually, the SQL Server scan for startup procs configuration
>   option can be set using sp_configure to prevent all stored procedures
>   from executing automatically when SQL Server starts. To skip launching
>   these stored procedures, specify trace flag 4022 as a startup
>   parameter. If you start SQL Server with minimal configuration (using
>   the -f flag), the startup stored procedures are not executed. For more
>   information, see Trace Flags.